# Getting a run time error when calling a function that uses a "for" loop to fill the data of a global structure

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and have been playing around with functions. So I've decided to make a simple program that gets the user's score for the movies he/she has watched.

The code in question is incomplete; but I ran into an error while testing along the way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE * fptr;

struct movie_show
{
    char movie_title[50];
    float movie_story, movie_characters, movie_art;
    float average_score;
};

/*************************************************************************/

int main()
{
    printf("[MOVIE RATER]\n\n");

    NumMovie();
    RatingMovie();

    printf("\n\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}

/*************************************************************************/

void NumMovie()
{
    int num_movie;

    printf("How many movies would you like to rate: ");
    scanf(" %d", &num_movie);

        if(num_movie < 1)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

    RatingMovie(num_movie);

}

/**************************************************************************/

void RatingMovie(int num_movie)
{
    int i;
    struct movie_show mov_show[num_movie];

    for (i = 0; i < num_movie; i++)
    {

        printf("movie #%d", i + 1);
        getchar();
        printf("\nTitle: ");
        fgets(mov_show[i].movie_title, 50, stdin);
        scanf(" %s", mov_show[i].movie_title);

        printf("\nBased on a 1-10 rating scale, how would you rate the: ");
        printf("\nStory: ");
        scanf(" %f", &mov_show[i].movie_story);

    }



}
```

This function in particular makes the program stop after executing the loops:

```
void RatingMovie(int num_movie)
{
    int i;
    struct movie_show mov_show[num_movie];

    for (i = 0; i < num_movie; i++)
    {

        printf("movie #%d", i + 1);
        getchar();
        printf("\nTitle: ");
        fgets(mov_show[i].movie_title, 50, stdin);
        scanf(" %s", mov_show[i].movie_title);

        printf("\nBased on a 1-10 rating scale, how would you rate the: ");
        printf("\nStory: ");
        scanf(" %f", &mov_show[i].movie_story);

    }



}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the error? Did you search what the error was?

Comment: Where does it crash ?

Comment: you need to make function declaration before main: 
void RatingMovie(int num_movie);
void NumMovie();

Comment: Delete `scanf(" %s", mov_show[i].movie_title);` and `RatingMovie();`

Comment: struct movie_show mov_show[num_movie]; - num_movie must be const or you need dynamically allocate memory: struct *movie_show mov_show = malloc(num_movie* sizeof(movie_show ));

Comment: 'scanf(" %d", &num_movie);' It would be a good idea to check the return value.

Comment: BTW `struct movie_show mov_show[num_movie];` is local variable.

Comment: struct movie_show mov_show is local variable but num_movie is function parameter and we cannot create array, num_movie must be declare in method with const or we need to use malloc

Answer (score 0):

In your `main()`, you call

```
   RatingMovie();
```

But RatingMovie's definition is

```
void RatingMovie(int num_movie);
```

Indicates `RatingMovie()` expects an int as a parameter.

Since you did not declare `RatingMovie()` before caling it in `main()`, the compiler at that point thinks RatingMovie takes no parameter and returns an int.

At runtime, when your program calls `RatingMovie()` from `main()`, `RatingMovie(int num_movie)` receives garbage as its `num_movies` parameter, resulting in undefined behavior.  In  this case your program crashes, probably because `num_movie` is negative or really big.

Other issues are imho:

- You call `RatingMovie()` twice in your code.  Pick one.
- `struct movie_show mov_show[num_movie];`  num_movie is not a constant, this is non-standard C.  Use a constant for the maximum of movies, or allocate an array with `calloc()` or `malloc()`
- calling `exit(0);` from `NumMovie()`  is not very elegant.  There must be a more elegant way of handling exit as part of the normal flow of your app.

If you move all of your function bodies before main(), and reorder your functions and fix all issues until your compiler issues **no more warnings**, your program should run fine.

Comment: Dynamically sized arrays have been part of the C standard since 1999, almost 20 years ago.

Comment: Maybe for gnu C, Microsoft C, and most others do not support dynamic sized arrays.  Doing so on VC 14.1: `error C2057:  expected constant expression` tested right now, with `/TC`

Comment: Visual Studio is pretty much just a [C++ compiler](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2089423-c99-support) that pretends to be a C compiler when applied to C files.  I'd be interested to see what it does on C files where C and C++ subtly differ (e.g. - operation sequencing + side effects, etc.).

Comment: That's what I just tested. On a C file, the  /TC flag meaning ' compile as C'. CL 14.1 is the latest version of their compiler.   There are many other compilers that do not support and have never supported dynamic array notation.  The 8051 compiler comes to mind, that's another MS compiler.  The PICC compilers do not either. afaik, it's a gcc extension.  the MS compiler is used a lot for C projects, especially for device drivers.

Comment: Dynamic arrays are not a gcc extension.  Like I said, they are part of the C standard from 1999 and again in 2011.  That Visual Studio explicitly chooses to only implement the C standard from 1990 (if that's what they actually do) is their choice, but in no way defines what valid C code is.  Both gcc and clang support them, for example.

Comment: That got my curiosity going...  Variably modified arrays are implementation dependent since C11.  They are still part of the standard, but support is not required.  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array, for what it's worth.